# RPC sensor model coefficient auxiliary data structure

Tags: remote-sensing, envi, orthorectification

I am part of a college team building a hyperspectral small satellite (3U). We would like to use ENVI's orthorectification module to do ortho. However, we need to generate our own RPC or sensor model. What is the general structure for an XML or txt of an RPC to be read by ENVI or even ArcMap for that matter? I cannot seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use GDAL conventions (you can see them here: https://gdal.org/development/rfc/rfc22_rpc.html) that relies on what you can find in the satellite business (such as DIMAP format).

GDAL is widely used in opensource community, and maybe ENVI and ArcMap can ingest them as well.